# Angular 4 + Jest-Preset-Angular : testing animation on host with trigger imported from file

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-animations

I am having an issue issue when running tests with [Jest-Preset-Angular](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular) on a component that has an animation on host element imported from a seperate file (so it can be reused in another component).

**example.animation.ts**

```js
import { trigger } from '@angular/animations';

export const ExampleAnimationHost = { '[@example]': '' };
export const ExampleAnimationTrigger = trigger('example', []);
```

**example.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleAnimationHost, ExampleAnimationTrigger } from './example.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
  animations: [ExampleAnimationTrigger],
  host: ExampleAnimationHost,
})
export class ExampleComponent { }
```

The fact is that if I *copy-paste* the trigger into the `animations` property of the `@Component` decorator my test pass ... otherwise it fails as it doesn't seems to find the animation declaration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer my own question if any body ever have the same problem.

There is an issue [here](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/22#issuecomment-297557830) specifying that you need to put the `animations` property **before** the `styleUrls` property in the `@Component` decorator.

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleAnimationHost, ExampleAnimationTrigger } from './example.animation';

@Component({
  animations: [ExampleAnimationTrigger], // must be place before styleUrls
  host: ExampleAnimationHost,
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
})
export class ExampleComponent { }
```

And voila!

Comment: Wow thank you, it solve my issue too! I I was a bit sceptic but it actually work :D